# Why is the Union of the Orthonormal Basis of $W$ and of $W^{\perp}$ an orthonormal Basis of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space with a dot product. Let $T \in L(V)$ (endomorphism) be a self-adjoint operator ($\forall x, y \in V, T(x) \cdot y = x \cdot T(y)$)

Let $W$ be an invariant subspace of $V$ by $T$.

Let $W^{\perp}=\{y \in V , y\cdot w = O, \forall w \in W\}$ be a subspace of $V$  (we know it to be invariant by $T$).

- Then the union of the orthonormal basis of $W$ and $W^{\perp}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$

**The proof goes like this :**

"Using Gram-Schmidt's method, we can orthonormalize any basis of $W$ and $W^{\perp}$. The reunion of both orthonormalized basis is an orthonormal basis of  V"

I hav no further  information

**Could someone clarify as to why the reunion of both orthonormalized basis is an orthonormal basis of  $V$?**

Comment: To check that a basis is orthonormal, it's enough to check that all of its elements have length $1$ and that its elements are pairwise orthogonal.

Comment: It's Gram-Schmidt, not Graham-Schmidt. After Jørgen Pedersen Gram and Erhard Schmidt.

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't help me to understand the proof

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a basis $V_W$ for $W$ and a basis $V_{W^{\perp}}$ for $W^{\perp}$. Using Gram-Schmidt's method, you find a orthonormal basis $V^{'}_W$ for $W$ and a orthonormal basis $V^{'}_{W^{\perp}}$ for $W^{\perp}$.

Now, you know that $W \cap W^{\perp} = \emptyset$, so given $u_1 \in V^{'}_{W}$ and $u_2 \in V^{'}_{W^{\perp}}$, you have that they are orthogonal. 
So, $V^{'}_{W^{\perp}} \cup V^{'}_{W}$ is an orthogonal basis for V.

It is trivial that each vector in $V^{'}_{W^{\perp}} \cup V^{'}_{W}$ has norm 1.

Comment: Yes it is trivial that $V^{'}_{W^{\perp}} \cup V^{'}_{W}$

Comment: Why do we know that $W \cap W^{\perp} = \emptyset$

Comment: Because of the definition of $W^{\perp}$